# XML reader error: unexpected character content exception while invoking webservice

Tags: java, xml, exception, webservice-client

Am trying to invoke a public web-service using a java client but am getting the following exception:

```
deserialization error: XML reader error: unexpected character content: "<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rankedTermCandidates 
  xmlns="http://www.nactem.ac.uk/xsd/termine" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nactem.ac.uk/xsd/termine http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/termine/webservice/termine.xsd" 
  >
```

Am not able to find out what I am doing wrong.
Am tempted to move to a .NET client{am a c# programmer} but would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

The method calling the webservice is :

```
    private String InvokeNactemWebService(String textToParse) throws Exception
{

String wsdlURL = "http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/termine/webservice/termine.wsdl";
URL url = new URL(wsdlURL);
String targetNamespace = "urn:termine";
String   serviceName = "termine";
String      portName = "termine_porttype";
String operationName = "analyze";
QName    serviceQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, serviceName);
QName       portQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, portName);
QName  operationQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, operationName);

String parseResult = "";

try
{
      ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
      Service service = serviceFactory.createService(url, serviceQN);

      Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
      call.setProperty(Call.ENCODINGSTYLE_URI_PROPERTY, "");
      call.setProperty(Call.OPERATION_STYLE_PROPERTY, "rpc");
      call.setTargetEndpointAddress("http://www.nactem.ac.uk:9000/termine");


      call.setPortTypeName(portQN);
      call.setOperationName(operationQN);

      call.removeAllParameters();
      call.addParameter("src",           XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("input_format",  XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("output_format", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("stoplist",      XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("filter",        XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);


      Object[] inParams = new Object[] {textToParse, "", "xml", "", ""};

      Object result = call.invoke(inParams);
      //parseResult = (String) call.invoke(inParams);
      //System.out.println(call.invoke(inParams));
      return parseResult;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Debug.println(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }

    return parseResult;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a [byte-order-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your XML response. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639810/jax-ws-errors-when-soap-body-contains-utf-8-bom) for further details. Capturing the response using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or similar will indicate what's going on.

If you do have a BOM, I suspect you can install a servlet filter to intercept the response before the webservice XML parsing code, and remove the BOM from the raw response before passing it forward.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Thats correct. The following is the exception stacktrace:<?xml version="1.0" ?> But am not able to find how the BOM can be removed from the response. Specifically, I would like to do the following: (call.invoke(inParams)).RemveBOM(); Is there a quick way to do this in Java? The link you mentioned shows the workaround for a .NET client.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late, but I believe all you need to do is set the return type that you'll be expecting, like:

```
call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);
```

This did the trick for my TerMine client :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Service service = serviceFactory.createService(url, serviceQN);
```

to

```
Service service = serviceFactory.createService(serviceQN);
```

-

so that you can add this to your code..

```
call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);
```